# Rotate an object to face a point with glm::lookAt

Tags: mathematics, rotation, glm

I want to rotate an object to face a point, such as the monster look at the player.

For that I've decided to use the glm::lookAt function. However the following does not yield good results:

```
const glm::mat4 transformation = glm::lookAt(ghostPosition, cameraPosition, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
ghost.transformation = transformation;
```

The ghost is correctly oriented to the player but is located to the world origin.
However the following works correctly (position and orientation):

```
const glm::mat4 transformation = glm::inverse(glm::lookAt(ghostPosition, cameraPosition, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)))
```

But I don't get why I need to inverse the matrix ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `lookAt` function is to position the camera to look at an object (not for an object to look at another object) and the way 3D **cameras** work is that mathematically they **move the entire world the opposite way** and the screen stays at the origin.

So because the matrix is intended for a camera and 3d cameras work "backward" you need to inverse the matrix to get an object to look at another object.